# Subquery returns more than 1 row, how can I solve?

Tags: mysql, sql

Question: Show the category of competitions that have always been hosted in the same country during May 2010. What is wrong with my query?

```
select Category
from competition
where Date >= '2010-01-01' and Date <= '2010-12-31'
group by Country, Category
having count(*) = (select count(*)
            from competition
            where Date >= '2010-01-01' and Date <= '2010-12-31'
            group by Category)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two queries. Just use one query that checks that the count of countries is 1.

```
select category, count(DISTINCT country) AS country_count
from competition
where Date BETWEEN '2010-05-01' and '2010-05-31'
group by Category
HAVING country_count = 1
```

I also corrected the dates to be just May, not the whole year 2010.

Comment: No, the question says ALWAYS choose only one city for some time, only one city

Comment: Where does the question say that?

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about cities, it says categories and countries.

Comment: If you only want one result, use `LIMIT 1` at the end.

Comment: thank you, I’ve already solved this problem and I meant the countries, and yes it says that in a certain time to settle in only one city

Comment: The question says "Show the category of competitions that have always been hosted in the same country during May 2010." Where does that say only one?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `GROUP BY` if you that is making you return more than 1 row (in your `HAVING CLAUSE`. If you give me an example dataset and what you want I can help you more

Comment: Then it won't compare the counts in the main query with the same category.

Comment: @barmar, you are correct. Without a dataset and an expected input/output all I can do is point out where your query is blowing up and why.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this to start with:

```
SELECT COUNTRY
, CATEGORY
, COUNT(COUNTRY)
FROM COMPETITION
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2010-04-30' AND '2010-06-01'
ORDER BY CATEGORY DESC, COUNT(COUNTRY) DESC
;
```

Your original query's date limits are just for the year of 2010 but you specified you only wanted May 2010. If the Date column is a date or datetime time you'll need to cast the string to the appropriate datatype.

Your question asked "always hosted by *one* country" - do you know that a competition is only going to be hosted by one country during that particular month? If you do, you're pretty much done. If you don't, however, then you need to clarify what your criteria really are

Comment: yes about the date I agree, but it’s not such a big problem. I have to decide how to make count() take the value more than 1 row